# Identity field disbaled in SQL Server Enterprise Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

I know the above code is for making a table in coding type, but my SQL Server Enterprise Manager doesn't support making tables or database in query mode

I have already made a database and tables using design view, but when I click on the column of the primary key the identity/increment is disabled? I need it for my system in vb

Comment: Not sure what you mean by disabled, should be able to set in your column properties window (assuming SSMS).  Look for Identity Specification.

Comment: Is your question about MySQL, or MS SQL Server? The tags and code example suggest one, but the title and prose the other...

Comment: Microsoft SQL Enterprise Manager

Microsoft Corporation

Version: 8.0 this is written in the about of the sql system

Comment: its disabled. its grayed out, i cant input on the identity field

Comment: Use the SQL Query Analyzer. It allows running whatever SQL you want (DDL, DML, ...). But seriously: Your are still using SQL Server 2000 and SQL Enterprise Manager/SQL Query Analyzer?

Answer (score 1):

You are using SQL Server from Microsoft, which uses IDENTITY columns instead of AUTO_INCREMENT

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

If you insist on using the Enterprise Manager, you can expand the tree to the database\table. Right click on the table in the list and choose "Design Table".  When you have the column `p_id` chosen, at the bottom you will be able to drop down the IDENTITY setting to change to "Yes".

[image]

Comment: yes idendity is the new word for increment but it does not support query builder

Comment: Wow, you still have a machine running these tools? :-)

Comment: ill be posting my database wait sir

Comment: i think i found the error why it is disabled,  i think it does not accepts varchar,   but how will it be if my primary key is OE_ID ex. is OEQ-SU-001

Comment: An IDENTITY value auto-increments a numeric(38,0) or compatible (e.g. int, bigint) column. It will never work on a VARCHAR column.

Comment: @ZombieHunter You never know when these questions will turn up! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SQL Query Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216945%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). It allows running whatever SQL you want (DDL, DML, ...).

As far as I can remember, SQL Server Enterprise Manager is more like a WYSIWYG editor for managing SQL Server 2000, while SQL Query Analyzer is more for the plain SQL scripting. But it's long time ago since I last used these tools...

Comment: i tried just now, it executes and makes a table but it does not save to my database

Comment: Your SQL statement creates a table (DDL), how do you expect it to save data/records (DML)?

Comment: then using sql query analyzer is useless, even though it executed how can i make my id identity work

Comment: @ivandinglasan: It is not useless at all. But you need to know what you want to do. To insert data into your table, run an INSERT statement.